# Остановка движение объекта. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня такой код:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    posX = document.querySelector('.player').offsetLeft;
    xn = posX - 150;
    document.querySelector('.player').style.left = xn + 'px';
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    // Что тут писать???
  }
}
```

```css
.player {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 6%;
  height: 17.3%;
  background: url(img/start.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 68%;
  transition: left .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <!-- Персонаж -->
</div>
```

Когда я зажимаю кнопку - ***стрелку влево***, объект движется нормально, а когда отпускаю, объект ещё сдвигается на **150px** влево.

Как можно переделать этот код так, чтобы когда я отпускаю клавишу клавиатуры, объект сразу же останавливался и не продолжал сдвигаться ещё на **150px**?

Answer (score 1):

Объект будет двигаться по заданным правилам CSS еще 0.5 сек. Вы можете его остановить, задав дельту изменений в 0 у анимации

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    posX = document.querySelector('.player').offsetLeft;
    xn = posX - 150;
    document.querySelector('.player').style.left = xn + 'px';
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    posX = document.querySelector('.player').offsetLeft;
    xn = posX;
    document.querySelector('.player').style.left = xn + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.player {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 6%;
  height: 17.3%;
  background: url(img/start.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 68%;
  transition: left .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <!-- Персонаж -->
</div>
```